# location.reload() is throwing retry/cancel prompt in IE

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: "/AdminInterface/AddPosition",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddPosition", "AdminInterface")',
            data: "{PosName:'" + PosText + "'}",//
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                //SuccessMsg("New Position Added.");
                location.reload();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
```

Here I am refreshing the webgrid in `location.reload()` but it is throwing a retry/cancel prompt in IE and firefox.In chrome it is working fine.
How to do it without losing the post data?

```
window.location.href = window.location.href

window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search

window.location = window.location.pathname;
```

Above all 3 are losing post data.

Comment: Instead of making POST, make it GET, in that way you will not get refresh prompt and also you will not loose data.

Comment: What have your tried and what is not working?

Comment: i tried to make it as GET, but still it is not working